# How to resize a Libgdx desktop window in-code during runtime

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Problem finding out how to resize a window in-code during runtime.

I have tried using Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(); but it removes the ability to resize the window, wich is a must in my game. I tried to access the Display class from openGL but without any luck, since it is not referenced in the Core part of gradle.

Any Idea how to get this done?

Comment: What do you mean, `removes the ability to resize the window`? Is this no longer allowed by the user or in the code?
EDIT: I just tested this out myself, and `Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(...);` works fine for me, I've set `config.resizable = true` and I'm able to resize it multiple times and resize it with my cursor.

Comment: when I invoke setDisplayMode it cannot be resized by the user anymore... it works just fine before that.

Comment: If you could provide some code with what you did, and where it stops allowing you to resize your window, it will help. It might even be a bug in LibGDX for your operating system.

Also, here's the test I did on one of my projects: http://pastebin.com/8NCkzgug

Comment: I call this: Gdx.graphics.setDisplayMode(Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().width - 50, Gdx.graphics.getDesktopDisplayMode().height - 50, false);  then it cannot be resized anymore...

Comment: I tried the same code, and I can still resize it manually. Once again, this might be a bug in LibGDX for your Operating System (I'm running Win7). But you can `edit your post with your code` so it can be double checked to make sure it's not a silly mistake.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SGaRtn6M here is the link to the main rendering classes in my project.

Comment: is `SetResizable(false)` ever called? Your provided code doesn't show a reason why it should stop being allowed to resize.

Also, after the line that you said it's no longer resizable, put a debug message after it for seeing if `Display.isResizable() == false`.

Comment: Actually, I do not have access to the Display Class...

Comment: You can always modify your dependencies. Look in the `.gradle` folder for them.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with exactly the same problem, and then I figured out, that instead of the direct call to `Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height))`, we should use `Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(width, height)` to change the window size.